# ASP.NET MVC Display SQL Server table data

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

On my second hitch on my journey to learning SQL, I've been following a tutorial but for some reason I cannot get my table to display its data on my page.

On the ready(function) part of the code, I have tried using 3 different ways of calling the column names (as they have a space in them, foolish error of mine!) to see which one works, but I have a feeling its the #CBR aspect of the code not contacting the database properly? 
Have I missed something obvious?

I have pasted the code from my View page and Controller below.

All help kindly received! and Thanks in advance! :)

```
@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Safes</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto">
    <table id="CBR">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Safe ID</th>
                <th>Department ID</th>
                <th>Safe Owner ID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>       
    </table>
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var otable = $('#CBR').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": '/home/GetSafe',
                "type": "get",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Safe ID", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "[Department ID]", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "User_ID", "autoWidth": true }
            ]
        })
    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And Controller excerpt:

```
public ActionResult Safes()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your Safe Page";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetSafe()
    {

        using (CBREntities dc = new CBREntities())
        {
            var safe = dc.Safes.OrderBy(a => a.User_ID).ToList();
            return Json(new { data = safe }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any exception on browser console ? What happens when you run your code? any screenshot would be helpful. 
What is the result when you call http://localhost:blabla/home/GetSafe ? do you have any result ?

Comment: I can open the pages perfectly fine, just no data from the table being displayed. I've added some screenshots to give some more names and info etc if they help? The latter being the result when I open the page :)

Comment: Could you please add ss of http://localhost:57444/home/GetSafe?

Comment: And have a look at your console log. Press F12 to see on the page. More details: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Comment: Find out at what step your logic is failing.  Test to see if your server code is actually pulling the data by setting a breakpoint.  If that works, test to see if your JavaScript code is capturing the data correctly.  Etc Etc..

Comment: I seem to recall that datatables can be quite strict with naming. If your <th> names don't match your data names exactly then you have to declare them as <td> items that match the data.

Comment: @ibrahimozgon Ah! Each of those came up with a good size of error! (Screenshots added) Though it's saying the Jquery wasn't defined? have I written them wrong?

Comment: your jquery script isnt being referenced properly. the first error shows that it is unable to be found. the remaining errors are caused by it not being able to be found

Comment: First, change your jquery script with this one:
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
You don't have that file on your server.

Answer (score 0):

First, 
Change your jquery script with this one:

```
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Seems, You don't have that file on your server.

Second,
the c# exception says, you closed your connection and you can't select new items from db. Try this with connection. Sometimes this happen when you have virtual property(lazy loading)

```
    var safe = dc.Safes.OrderBy(a => a.User_ID).Select(s=>
new{SafeID=s.SafeID,
DepartmentID=s.DepartmentID, 
User_ID=s.User_ID}
).ToList();
```

Comment: I replaced <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script> with that one. And done the below too, but yields the same error? In fact, that Jquery script flags up a yellow "cannot find on server" warning in VS? I will add a screenshot of the scripts library.

Comment: Worth of note though... When trying the http://localhost:blah/Home/GetSafe, it DOES yield the database data now! ?

Comment: But the regular page still doesn't?